# Background image and fixed height sticky footer

Tags: html, css

This is an skeleton of my html/css: http://jsfiddle.net/GMg7B/.

Now I want to add a background image for the `div#content` part so that:

- It resizes to fit its container (something like `background: cover`)
- Doesn't overlap with the footer.
- Aspect ratio of the image is kept.
- Height of background image is adjusted to fit "screen's full height minus footer height", padded with white background on the sides to fill full width if necessary.
- Footer has fixed height, it's always pushed to the bottom of the page and remains visible without a scrollbar, independently of the screen's height.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't overlap with the footer". You have set a `-120px` margin on the content to the footer will always be overlapping. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/GMg7B/2/) <- Like that?

Comment: in your fiddle, the footer is not fixed width

Comment: What's wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/GMg7B/3/

Comment: Sorry, fixed height I meant.

Comment: @deivid Your not being clear, do you want the aspect ratio to be the same or just stretch?

Comment: @Ruddy I've edited the question, hopefully I'm more clear now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @deivid : your footer *is at* the bottom....check my fiddles, also, if you want to place them semantically correct way then give, `#content` => `min-height: 400px;height:100%;` and `body` => `height:100%`

Comment: @deivid NoobEditor's second demo "cover demo" does all of this so thats the correct answer Theres no reason for you to have the `-margin` so just leave the `footer` under the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to you `#content` cs

```
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size:  100% 100%;
```

**why is it stretching to footer??** because your  line `margin: 0 auto -120px;` is conflicting with the `footer`

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GMg7B/1/)

even `background-size: cover;` works if you remove the `-120px` margin!!

[**cover demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GMg7B/4/)

Maintain aspect ration of  bg image :

[**aspect ratio demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GMg7B/5/) 
just remove `fixed` from my above quoted css and you are done!!

**As for footer to stay at bottom**

you can use css `calc()` method:

something like :

```
#footer{
  margin-top : calc(100% - footer_height_in_px); /* default */
  margin-top : -moz-calc(100% - footer_height_in_px); /* moz */
  margin-top : -webkit-calc(100% - footer_height_in_px); /* webkit browsers */

}
```

Refer these links if it intersets you :

- http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: Why are you always around! +1 as I think this is what the OP is asking for. Even tho the OP has a odd `-120px margin` on the content for some reason.

Comment: @Ruddy : hi...its either me or Alien that you have as a friend....so just thought of passing by!!

Comment: Thanks @NoobEditor, I'm trying your fiddle's right now, I've edited my question again. I'm having a hard time to make myself understood, sorry.

Comment: @deivid : whats giving you hard time...may be i can help you understand!! :)

Comment: Final specs in the question I think! If I drop the negative margin, a scroll bar appears, I want the footer to stay visible at the bottom without a scrollbar. One million thanks!

Comment: @deivid : you want the footer to be visible at all times??? paste the url of fiddle you referencing to, m sure, m misunderstanding smthng.... :)

Comment: I think this is gonna be easier: http://www.aroundyoga.com/. The footer must stay visible at the bottom at any screen height, but shouldn't overlap with the background map.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45175/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-deivid)